# Is OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD a good solution for authorizing app users?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I am building a Xamarin app that will need to have users authenticated and each user will have a role. Would Azure AD OAuth 2.0 be a good solution for this scenario? Each person that downloads my app would register which would create an Azure AD user? At first I thought Azure AD was strictly for managing users within an organizations and not a way to authorize thousands of users of an app. Would I be able to seamlessly integrate Azure OAuth into my app without having to leave my app (like I would need to do with Google or Facebook OAuth)? Thanks for any clarification that would help me better understand!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin experience can leverage ADAL / MSAL PCL libraries for authentication (in Alpha right now) - [available on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/1.0.303282006-alpha). You need to look at the new [Azure AD Business to Consumer (B2C)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) offering (in preview right now).

Note that the OAuth experience this provides leverages WebViews inside of your app to perform user authentication so it doesn't differ from what you wish to avoid.

While you could theoretically change that behaviour by custom coding a solution it's probably worth considering the benefits of handing off authentication and only having to deal with the resulting tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see the Azure AD B2C offering says "Let consumers use their social media accounts"  does this mean my users would be required to log in with a Facebook, Google, etc account, or would they be able to register an account that is unique to my Xamarin app? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I notice the only Azure services available to me in the portal are: Azure AD Cloud App Discovery, Azure AD Connect Health, Azure AD Connect Health, Azure AD Privileged Identity Management... Which one is the B2C offering you mentioned? And if it is in preview, do you happen to know if it is available for production use now? Thanks!     ***EDIT*** nevermind, I just found the B2C... it wasn't showing up in the search because it is preview I guess.

Comment: I currently have a website in the Azure "Default Directory" AD directory. Today I tested creating a new B2C AD directory. If I decide to pursue this strategy, would you recommend that I move my website into the same B2C AD directory? This website along with my Xamarin app would both need to authenticate against the Azure B2C service. Thanks for any help, I haven't seen a lot of documentation about this out there.